# What settings are required to ensure that changes to CSS / SCSS occur dynamically in development?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

Using Rails 4.

In development, every time I make a change to CSS / SCSS files, I have to issue:

```
rails assets:clobber
```

and then restart my server to effect the change.  Obviously, this is slow and frustrating.

Within development.rb, I have set:

```
  config.serve_static_files = false
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  config.assets.digest = false
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.compile = true
```

In unsuccessful attempts to rectify this problem.

My application.scss file uses @import instead of require, if this makes a difference:

```
/*
*= require_self
*/
@import 'reset';
@import 'scaffolds';
@import 'dataTables/extras/dataTables.responsive';
@import 'dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap';
@import 'font-awesome-sprockets';
@import 'font-awesome';
/*
 *= require_tree .
*/
@import '_bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'kc.scss';
```

I understand there is probably duplication and some tuning is required, but even that is difficult with my current issue so I need it solved first.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config/environments/development.rb, set:

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

Page refreshes will load new assets.  However, page loads will be very slow, so you might want to only set this while you are actually changing the assets.

I removed all of the other options.  I assume that one was causing some conflict that precompiled and loaded fixed assets.